# Cloudflare R2 - Delete all objects from bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, cloudflare, cloudflare-r2

### Is there an easy way to delete all objects from a Cloudflare R2 bucket?

This isn't something I'd want to do in production, but something that I want to do while testing in development. I'd love to be able to select more than 25 objects at a time from the dashboard or delete all objects from a CLI.

Comment: I've never used this but it seems you can use the `aws cli` - https://developers.cloudflare.com/r2/examples/aws-cli/ - so maybe `aws s3 rm --endpoint-url https://<accountid>.r2.cloudflarestorage.com --recursive` will delete everything? Be careful, I didn't test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do this from the Rails Console using ActiveStorage

```rb
ActiveStorage::Blob.services.fetch(:cloudflare_user_pictures).bucket.objects.batch_delete!
```

Where `:cloudflare_user_pictures` is the name of your service.

I run this at the end of my test suite to remove all pictures from the test buckets on cloudflare:

```rb
Minitest.after_run do
  ActiveStorage::Blob.services.fetch(:cloudflare_user_pictures).bucket.objects.batch_delete!
  ActiveStorage::Blob.services.fetch(:cloudflare_chat_message_attachments).bucket.objects.batch_delete!
end
```

Answer (score 19):

Thanks to Juan Fontes' comment above, I tried this out and the following worked.

```
aws s3 rm s3://<bucket-name> --endpoint-url https://<cloudflare-id>.r2.cloudflarestorage.com --recursive --dryrun
```

After it's working for you, rerun without the `--dryrun` flag.

Don't forget to [configure](https://developers.cloudflare.com/r2/examples/aws-cli/) the AWS CLI first.

Answer (score 1):

There is an alternative way to achieve this by using lifecycle settings in the bucket configuration:

[image]

Setting "Delete uploaded objects after" to 0 will empty the whole bucket the next day